# How to close the test browser when a functional test fails?

Tags: intern

When running a functionnal test with Intern, I've noticed that the test browser (google chrome in my case) automatically close when the test succeeed, but is not closed when the test fail.

Is there a way to have the browser close even when a test fail ?

Comment: Please be more specific: What tools do you use? How are your tests run?

Comment: I'm running a functional test using the node runner (node runner.js config=my/config), with only one browser environment configured, for google chrome. Should I understand from your question that the normal behavior is for the test browser to be closed when a test is terminated, either on a success or a failure ?

Answer (score 0):

Test browsers are always instructed to quit regardless of whether or not the test run succeeded or failed. If they are not quitting, it is probably because of a fatal error elsewhere (closed socket, etc.) that prevents Intern from sending the quit command to the browser.